# Can not read from Synology NAS from Windows OS, but Linux access works fine

Tags: windows, samba, network-attached-storage, synology

So as mentioned in the title: we have a Windows machine here needing access to a samba share on a Synology NAS. This machine can not access it and Windows responds with "wrong username/password". But when I try to access it from my machine running Linux smb works fine. Interesting: in the logs from the NAS i can see the access attempt from my Linux machine but no message about the access attempt from the Windows machine. But I think this is just due to the log config(so unsuccessful attempt do not get logged)? I am confusion! Any suggestions on what the issue might be?

Comment: Normally we would use the term "accessibility" to describe whether a device is reachable over the network. Your problem is better described as an authentication issue. We don't need to see the passwords but it would help to see what you are providing as the username in both scenarios, and whether the Synology device or MS-Windows client are part of a domain.

Comment: symcbean's comment is particularly on point now that Windows 11 is refusing to connect to SMB shares with Guest authentication.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect use of the term accessibility. I changed the title (and provided the answer). So regarding the users, I did not try to use the guest user, but set up a proper user to access the smb share. I used this user on both ends(Linux and Windows) and Windows was regretting to connect, but Linux did fine with the same credentials. As mentioned before, the answer is down below. Thanks for your time though!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Have you tried turning it off and on again?"...."whoops. Forgot. It is a windows machine..."
So after rebooting it just works. Don't ask me why.